# How do you fix the error code TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I am working on a chatbot and when trying to set how to train it I get the error message:

```
 TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

It's always on the exact same line:

```py
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train (  
    "chatterbot.corpus.english",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.conversations",
    "./data/greetings_corpus/custom.corpus.json",
    "./data/my_corpus/"
)
```

simply trying to input

```py
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)


trainer.train
```

gives the same results because it's not loading or something from what I know.

I don't know how to put a loader in. While the chatbot works perfectly fine without this code its stupid and cannot learn. Someone said that I need a loader parameter, but I don't have one in case anyone is wondering I'm using chatterbot.

I tried updating `yaml` to no luck and I tried implementing a loader but still no luck. I don't know what to do to fix this or how to implement a loader like it asks. What exactly do I need to do to make so it doesn't give me this error anymore?

Comment: Hello! Could you include a minimal reproducible example to help people answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok I think I did that